# How to get the errors message with spring mvc in tomcat's catalina.out

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, exception

I request a test link https://terran.gamebox.com/facebook/issueOrder.jhtml?amount=5&gameId=1&serverId=1&role=role
I can see the message in page
but the exception did not show in catalina.out

This is my configure file

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="com.gamebox.HandlerException">
```

`HandlerException` implements `HandlerExceptionResolver`

I must point that I can get the other controller's exception such as   `null pointer` exception

I guess it's a spring internal exception, but I need capture all exception in `catalina.out` file.

I create a `@Service` dependence in a `@Controller`, then delete the `@Service`'s class file.
When I started the `tomcat`, everything is OK, I request this controller, I got the exception message, but the `catalina.out` show nothing.  The `tomcat` ran in Run mode.

I paste the response message, because this mvc's action will fix next day with this bug, but I will trace nothing in my platform when I use a ajax with mvc in future if it doesn't show in catalina.out and I will be defficult to find nothing.

I am sure it involved transactionManager

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gamebox.service.FacebookPayOrderService
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2300)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1745)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:322)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:846)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod.createWithResolvedBean(HandlerMethod.java:220)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:240)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:298)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1091)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1076)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:896)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:270)
    com.gamebox.filter.SiteStatusFilter.doFilterInternal(SiteStatusFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

Comment: How does you logging config look?

Comment: it's a standard tomcat with no config. The System.out.print or e.printStackTrace() can show in catalina.out. I view some information about it. Maybe it involved Transactional rules.

Comment: another question is how to get the @transactional exceptions without try catch block

Answer (score 0):

All system out/error will go to catalina.out by default. Don't use System.out.println, use a logging API and configure your logger to write to the console.

If you are using something like logback, in your application just consider it to write to console:

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

to tame spring messages, you can remove commons-logging and use slf4j to route spring into the same logging. See this article
http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-log-in-spring-with-slf4j-and-logback/

That should help improve visibility and give you your goal of getting everything into catalina.out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it, and I find the exception message in tomcat base/logs/localhost.2014-09-04.log  I use my project in my computer, everything is OK. My OS is windows 7. But my server is Linux. I really didn't know what happened. I think each of stdout message will write to the catalina.out

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the solution and I am very satisfy.

Only one changed, edit the TOMCAT_HOME/conf/logging.properties file then locate this line:

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

Append , java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler to this line.

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

All exceptions will be write to catalina.out file.^_^